# Web server farms with IIS ? Basic Infos

Tags: iis, webserver, web-farm

Can somebody point me to a resource that explains how to go about having 2+ IIS web server clustered (or Webfarm not sure what its called) ?

All I need is something basic, an overview how and where to start.
Can't seem to find anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're after is called Load Balancing.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0baca8b1-73b9-4cd2-ab9c-654d88d05b4f.mspx?mfr=true

There's a very good book on the topic:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Windows-Clustering-Balancing-Osborne-Networking/dp/0072226226/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1219249588&sr=8-1

Comment: Actually much better tools to use here are the ApplicationRequestRouting module (2.0), WebFarmFramework (2.0) and WebDeploy (1.1). Will provide links in separate comment.

Comment: @andrew - in all fairness these tools weren't available when I answered the question so I think the downvote is a bit harsh. Also OP hasn't specified that he's using IIS7.

Answer (score 3):

This MSDN magazine article has a good overview of the technologies involved:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500561.aspx

Comment: great article, haven't seen it before

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft have articles on TechNet about [clustering IIS using Network Load Balancing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759613.aspx). You can do this more simply than using special hardware load balancing.

For hardware load balancing you place a device in front of the web servers and it manages the load. Each device is different so you would want to check the manufacturers guides and compatibility.

You should also check that your application does not have problems with load balancing. The [sticky session problem](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050929.htm) is just one problem you should find out more about.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.iis.net/download/applicationrequestrouting

http://www.iis.net/download/webfarmframework

http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy

Comment: Fine if the OP is running IIS7, but not so handy on IIS5/6.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of good articles for those who are looking nowadays for information about **Server Farms** - **Load Balancing** and **Application Request Rooting** that I found and wanted to share are these:

HTTP Load Balancing using Application Request Routing:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing.

Overview - Build a Web Farm with IIS Servers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-hosting/scenario-build-a-web-farm-with-iis-servers/overview-build-a-web-farm-with-iis-servers