# What is the difference between configurations of “Web farms” and “Web gardens”?

Tags: .net, configuration

What is the difference between Web Farms and Web Gardens, related to the server configuration section in .NET? How can we implement it?

Answer (score 1):

> A Web
> garden allows an application to
> achieve higher scalability, since
> multiple processes are used to process
> requests on its behalf. A Web garden
> is like a Web farm (in that it aims to
> achieve higher scalability), but
> within the confines of a single
> server.

SOURCE: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221042832/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/vkamat/archive/2004/11/17/15145.aspx)

Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

A Web farm allows you to expand a Web Site across multiple servers.

A Web garden allows you to expand a Web Site across multiple CPUs within a single server. Web garden feature comes with IIS 6 and above. It is useful when you have mulltiple processors and enough RAM.

Answer (score 1):

A [Web Farm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305/web-server-farms-with-iis-basic-infos) is a collection of servers, called a pool, that host a single site and the load is distributed amongst each machine using a load balancer. The load balancer can be configured to distribute the requests for the web site in a number of different ways either sequentially or dynamically based on current load of the machines.

A [Web Garden](https://web.archive.org/web/20150301162811/http://nicholas.piasecki.name:80/blog/2009/02/on-web-gardens-aspnet-and-iis-60/) is a single server that runs multiple instances of the w3p.exe worker process to serve a single site. Having multiple processes allows them to be allocated to separate CPUs or CPU cores and increases the overall number of threads the web site is capable of using.

Things to remember when running a website as a Farm is that you must manage the code base carefully to ensure each server has the same version of the website. [Scott Hanselman at MIX10](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/web-deployment-made-awesome-if-youre-using-xcopy-youre-doing-it-wrong) covers some greate techniques for managing deployment. Machines within the pool will not automatically share resources so you may need a [Distributed Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/brownfield/distributed-caching-and-scalability) and possibly file replication or a [Distributed File System](http://aspalliance.com/1037).

A Web Garden will not share InProc resources for obvious reasons and you should think carefully about the increased potential for dead locks and race conditions when using shared resources.